# ¿Cómo puedo recuperar el email del usuario que se registra en mi app con facebook?

Tags: android, email, facebook

Estoy intentando recuperar el email de alguien que se registra en mi app desde facebook pero no lo consigo.

El código que uso para recuperar el nombre, apellido, foto e Id, es el siguiente:

```
             LoginActivity:

    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");

            MainActivity:

Profile.getCurrentProfile().getName();   nombre entero
Profile.getCurrentProfile().FisrtName();   nombre
Profile.getCurrentProfile().getLastName() apellido
Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId();    id
Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri();  foto
```

pero el correo no se como recuperarlo.